# Get sum of every n th column for each individual and create new data frame in r

Tags: r, sum, seq, tapply

Having searched for similar posts, I am posting my question. I have monthly rainfall variables for several years for each site. I need to calculate monthly average rainfall over the years. I have given a simple data frame as follows. I need to create a new data frame that consists of monthly averages (12) for each site.

```
d<-structure(list(ID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), X2000_1 = c(25L, 42L, 74L, 52L), X2000_2 = c(15L, 
15L, 51L, 12L), X2000_3 = c(14L, 21L, 25L, 41L), X2000_4 = c(74L, 
4L, 23L, 51L), X2000_5 = c(15L, 25L, 65L, 12L), X2000_6 = c(31L, 
23L, 15L, 25L), X2001_1 = c(52L, 54L, 18L, 63L), X2001_2 = c(85L, 
165L, 12L, 12L), X2001_3 = c(25L, 36L, 20L, 14L), X2001_4 = c(1L, 
17L, 23L, 52L), X2001_5 = c(24L, 45L, 12L, 15L), X2001_6 = c(3L, 
23L, 45L, 52L)), .Names = c("ID", "X2000_1", "X2000_2", "X2000_3", 
"X2000_4", "X2000_5", "X2000_6", "X2001_1", "X2001_2", "X2001_3", 
"X2001_4", "X2001_5", "X2001_6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

The output should be like;

```
df<-data.frame(id = c("A","B","C","D"))
df[c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun")]<-NA
```

for example the cell A1 should contains the average rainfall of X2000_1 and X2001_1

I tried my codes as below but it does not work may be because I am using data frame. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
n = 6
unname(tapply(d, (seq_along(d)-1) %/% n, sum))
```

The column names of my actual data frame are

```
c("est", "X1990_1", "X1990_2", "X1990_3", "X1990_4", "X1990_5", 
"X1990_6", "X1990_7", "X1990_8", "X1990_9", "X1990_10", "X1990_11", 
"X1990_12", "X1991_1", "X1991_2", "X1991_3", "X1991_4", "X1991_5", 
"X1991_6", "X1991_7", "X1991_8", "X1991_9", "X1991_10", "X1991_11", 
"X1991_12", "X1992_1", "X1992_2", "X1992_3", "X1992_4", "X1992_5", 
"X1992_6", "X1992_7", "X1992_8", "X1992_9", "X1992_10", "X1992_11", 
"X1992_12", "X1993_1", "X1993_2", "X1993_3", "X1993_4", "X1993_5", 
"X1993_6", "X1993_7", "X1993_8", "X1993_9", "X1993_10", "X1993_11", 
"X1993_12", "X1994_1", "X1994_2", "X1994_3", "X1994_4", "X1994_5", 
"X1994_6", "X1994_7", "X1994_8", "X1994_9", "X1994_10", "X1994_11", 
"X1994_12", "X1995_1", "X1995_2", "X1995_3", "X1995_4", "X1995_5", 
"X1995_6", "X1995_7", "X1995_8", "X1995_9", "X1995_10", "X1995_11", 
"X1995_12", "X1996_1", "X1996_2", "X1996_3", "X1996_4", "X1996_5", 
"X1996_6", "X1996_7", "X1996_8", "X1996_9", "X1996_10", "X1996_11", 
"X1996_12", "X1997_1", "X1997_2", "X1997_3", "X1997_4", "X1997_5", 
"X1997_6", "X1997_7", "X1997_8", "X1997_9", "X1997_10", "X1997_11", 
"X1997_12", "X1998_1", "X1998_2", "X1998_3", "X1998_4", "X1998_5", 
"X1998_6", "X1998_7", "X1998_8", "X1998_9", "X1998_10", "X1998_11", 
"X1998_12", "X1999_1", "X1999_2", "X1999_3", "X1999_4", "X1999_5", 
"X1999_6", "X1999_7", "X1999_8", "X1999_9", "X1999_10", "X1999_11", 
"X1999_12", "X2000_1", "X2000_2", "X2000_3", "X2000_4", "X2000_5", 
"X2000_6", "X2000_7", "X2000_8", "X2000_9", "X2000_10", "X2000_11", 
"X2000_12")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the months as variable from the column names, and split the data frame as a list by the months variable and for each sub data frame calculate the row average with the `rowMeans()` function:

```
# extract the months for each column
mon <- sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", names(d)[-1])

# split the data frame by columns and calculate the rowMeans
cbind.data.frame(d[1], lapply(split.default(d[-1], mon), rowMeans))

#  ID    1    2    3    4    5    6
#1  A 38.5 50.0 19.5 37.5 19.5 17.0
#2  B 48.0 90.0 28.5 10.5 35.0 23.0
#3  C 46.0 31.5 22.5 23.0 38.5 30.0
#4  D 57.5 12.0 27.5 51.5 13.5 38.5
```

Comment: when the solution is used to another data frame similar to the example, an error message comes as Error in base::rowMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: What are the column names of your real data? And also run `lapply(d[-1], class)` to see if all columns except for the *ID* are numeric type.

Comment: In my real data all columns except ID are numeric type. I checked it. Only difference to the example is NAs for some months.

Comment: You can remove na by passing the `na.rm` parameter to `lapply` like `cbind.data.frame(d[1], lapply(split.default(d[-1], mon), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE))` but that doesn't match the error message. You also said that `mon` doesn't give `1,..6`, maybe that is the problem. What are the actual column names? Maybe they have multiple underscore `_`?

Comment: I checked but there is nothing wrong in column names all are the same way?

Comment: It creates only for month "12" but all others months as in the original name.

Comment: Can you `dput(names(d))`? I am curious why that would happen.

Comment: I included it at the end of my question. Please see it.

Comment: I replaced the `names(d)` in the first line with the vector you posted, it is giving `"1", "2", ...."11", "12"` back as expected.

Comment: d means the name of the data frame. So instead if I have given the data frame name as d2, the code should be  'mon <- sub(".*_(\\d2+)$", "\\1", names(d2)[-1])'    So I am also wondering why it does not give 1,..., 12

Comment: Ah, I see what's the problem. I should have explained better. The first `\\d+` is regex symbol, it stands for digits or [0-9] and it has nothing to do with the data frame name, so that should be left along. Try this instead, `mon <- sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", names(d2)[-1])`, or even `mon <- sub(".*_([0-9]+)$", "\\1", names(d2)[-1])`

Comment: Great thanks. I understand your code now and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with some `reshape`-ing to a long dataset, along with tabulation:

```
tmp <- reshape(d, idvar="ID", sep="_", direction="long", varying=-1)
xtabs(rowMeans(cbind(X2000,X2001)) ~ ID + time, data=tmp)
#   time
#ID     1    2    3    4    5    6
#  A 38.5 50.0 19.5 37.5 19.5 17.0
#  B 48.0 90.0 28.5 10.5 35.0 23.0
#  C 46.0 31.5 22.5 23.0 38.5 30.0
#  D 57.5 12.0 27.5 51.5 13.5 38.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `Reduce` with `+`

```
cbind(d[1], Reduce(`+`, list(d[2:7], d[8:13]))/2)
#    ID X2000_1 X2000_2 X2000_3 X2000_4 X2000_5 X2000_6
#1  A    38.5    50.0    19.5    37.5    19.5    17.0
#2  B    48.0    90.0    28.5    10.5    35.0    23.0
#3  C    46.0    31.5    22.5    23.0    38.5    30.0
#4  D    57.5    12.0    27.5    51.5    13.5    38.5
```

Or just

```
cbind(d[1], (d[2:7] + d[8:13])/2)
```

Comment: How NAs can be removed when calculating here

Comment: @sriya If there are NAs, the solution provided by psidom or thelatemail's solution is better as the `rowMeans` have `na.rm=TRUE` argument

Answer (score 1):

Assuming , we have first columns as `ID` and rest all columns are equally distributed.

Can we just, divide the dataframe into two halves and get the mean between them.

```
cbind(d[1],(d[2:ceiling(ncol(d)/2)] + d[(ceiling(ncol(d)/2) + 1):ncol(d)])/2)


#   ID X2000_1 X2000_2 X2000_3 X2000_4 X2000_5 X2000_6
#1  A    38.5    50.0    19.5    37.5    19.5    17.0
#2  B    48.0    90.0    28.5    10.5    35.0    23.0
#3  C    46.0    31.5    22.5    23.0    38.5    30.0
#4  D    57.5    12.0    27.5    51.5    13.5    38.5
```

Obviously, we can always do by hard coding the column numbers.

`cbind(d[1], (d[2:7] + d[8:13])/2)`

However, the above mentioned approach is generalized one and it will  work even if we have more than 13 columns.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, to get the Check-out information of a file you need to find out the workspaces and then find what are all pending changes on those work spaces.

Comment: @Psidom when the solution is used to another data frame similar to the example, an error message comes as Error in base::rowMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric . I believe that is something to do with mon here. Because when the mon is called it does not create 1, 6 but the original column names (X2000_1)